# How to update VSTS 2008 Team System Web Access to VSTS 2010

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

Is there something like VSTS2010 Team System Web Access (TSWA), if yes where is it located(web page, package with VSTS2010 installer), I'm searching for it but Microsoft pages directs me to VSTS2008 TSWA

I try to upgrade VSTS2008 to VSTS2010, after the upgrade I tried to access it through Team System Web Access and I got an error The type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WebAccess.DefaultPage' is ambiguous:it could come from assembly 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Team System Web Access\Wiwa\bin\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WebAccess.Server.DLL' or from assembly 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WebAccess.Server\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WebAccess.Server.dll'. Please specify the assembly explicitly in the type name.

Do you have an idea what should I do?

Comment: What is the URL you used to access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a clean install of TFS 2010, the Team Web Access is created to connect to the SharePoint portal. This of course happens when a team project is created. There's simply a "Team Web Access" link in the left navigation pane of the portal.

Try to right-click a team project in Team Explorer, and choose "Show Project Portal". See if you have that link in the right nav.